# Executing Curl in PHP to do a Stripe subscription

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments

The Stripe API allows for Curl calls to be made. For example, the command:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com//v1/customers/cus_5ucsCmNxF3jsSY/subscriptions    -u sk_test_REDACTED:
```

returns the subscription of customer cus_5ucsCmNxF3jsSY.

How can I use PHP to call this curl command (I am trying to avoid using the PHP Stripe libraries).

I am trying the following:

```
<?php 
        // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.stripe.com//v1/customers/cus_5ucsCmNxF3jsSY/subscriptions    -u sk_test_REDACTED:"); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 
        print($output);

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

However, it seems that curl does not take the -u parameter of the URL. I get the following error:

```
{ "error": { "type": "invalid_request_error", "message": "You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/." }
```

How can I pass the -u sk_test_REDACTED: parameter to my curl call?

Comment: "I am trying to avoid using the PHP Stripe libraries" **WHY?** Use their tested, reliable, well-maintained library and forget about it.

Comment: Also you should probably remove your secret key from your options, even if it is your test key you don't wan it visible

Comment: although its nearly 4 years later I am super glad this question was asked. It helped me answer my own issues. There are tons of examples of code all over the net but none of them seem to take into account things like customer canceling payment through their processor, insufficient funds, canceled cards, etc. Most of them expect a user will click cancel on a website. Using a full blown library is overkill for something a curl request can do. Your question unknowingly helped me sort my problems :)

Answer (score 18):

I ran into the same issue. I wanted to use PHP's CURL functions instead of using the official stripe API because singletons make me nauseous.

I wrote my own very simple Stripe class which utilizes their API via PHP and CURL.

```
class Stripe {
    public $headers;
    public $url = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/';
    public $fields = array();
    
    function __construct () {
        $this->headers = array('Authorization: Bearer '.STRIPE_API_KEY); // STRIPE_API_KEY = your stripe api key
    }
    
    function call () {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($this->fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($output, true); // return php array with api response
    }
}

// create customer and use email to identify them in stripe
$s = new Stripe();
$s->url .= 'customers';
$s->fields['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$customer = $s->call();

// create customer subscription with credit card and plan
$s = new Stripe();
$s->url .= 'customers/'.$customer['id'].'/subscriptions';
$s->fields['plan'] = $_POST['plan']; // name of the stripe plan i.e. my_stripe_plan
// credit card details
$s->fields['source'] = array(
    'object' => 'card',
    'exp_month' => $_POST['card_exp_month'],
    'exp_year' => $_POST['card_exp_year'],
    'number' => $_POST['card_number'],
    'cvc' => $_POST['card_cvc']
);
$subscription = $s->call();
```

You can dump $customer and $subscription via `print_r` to see the response arrays if you want to manipulate the data further.

Comment: Your class is great @daygloink, I impove it with a public variable $method. You can use it also with GET and POST.

Comment: Rolled back those changes. Please post code improvements that add functionality as a new answer.